# Why it doesn't use get or post method in XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
xhr.open('SDSERVICE' , url, true);
```

I am trying to understand what is purpose of SDSERVICE here, instead of using http request method like GET or POST.

Please anyone can elaborate this.

Answer (score 0):

The general idea here in regards to HTTP (as the protocol) is that there could be more of these "verbs"/"methods" (commands), to introduce and support more operations for the client to interact with the server. See, for example, WebDAV, which has HTTP verbs like `MOVE` and `COPY` remotely moving files on the server side around.

Often, however, client-side libraries and server-side implementations (as well as components, frameworks, programming languages) may not support more/other verbs than just `GET` and `POST` (which are the only two permitted in HTML forms), or the WWW's small set with additional `PUT`, `DELETE`, `HEAD`, `OPTIONS` + a few more uncommon ones (here, these are for interacting with WWW servers from a client that's not a browser or is a browser but not limited to only HTML forms).

In theory, you/anyone can come up with custom HTTP verbs, and then it depends on client libraries, programming languages, server-side implementation, if these

1. permit access to the HTTP verb used, supply/report which one was used to the developer
2. there's an operation implemented for these verbs

There's likely no point in sending a `SDSERVICE` request to a pure WWW server, because it won't understand/react to this verb/operation.

The WWW is a specialized application (use case) that uses HTTP (as protocol - could theoretically used other protocols as well, or support several protocols), mostly for Web/interlinked documents and nowadays increasingly for online/cloud SaaS apps. Especially in the latter case, the permitted WWW HTTP verbs may often turn out to be too limited (where the basic CRUD operations are not sufficient), which is where other, new HTTP verbs may be introduced. Another alternative is to put the desired operation into an URL parameter, so it's then not introduced on/per protocol level, but as part of the "payload"/hypermedium (in ReST terms).